# How to set up DSLR (Canon T3i) to work with opencv-python

Tags: python, camera, opencv

I'm looking to connect my DSLR (Canon T3i) - and generally any DSLR - for use with opencv-python. I'd ideally like to be able to do it via Windows or Linux. I've seen libgphoto2 mentioned (on the linux side) but have not found a general enough post on and forums to explain how to get opencv to recognize a connected DSLR via the "cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)"

Does anyone know how this is accomplished?